# Go: Array string "two word" value

Tags: arrays, go

I was quite confused and curious about the "two-word" value that is related to the `string` array in Go.

For example:

```golang
var strings [5]string
strings[0] = "Apple"
```

The `strings` is declared, and when assigned another `string`, it will be a two-word value that is copied.

Can someone help me understand what the "two-word" means here? And if there is/are resources where I can look up to, it will be a great help.

Comment: a string, in Go, is represented as a two-word data structure,the first word contains a pointer to the underlying character data, and the second word contains the length of the string, and when you assign a string value to an element of the array, the entire two-word value is copied to that element,this means that both the pointer to the character data and the length are copied. Therefore, modifying the string value in one element of the array does not affect the string value in other elements!

Comment: "Word" is a technical term for 8 bytes (on 32bit hardware for 4 bytes). The actual hardware works (often) with word-sized things like integers or pointers. So "two-words" means 16 bytes. The first 8 for the length and the second 8 for the address of the actual string content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @freeman, in golang, a string is a two-word data structure, one is a pointer to the actual place of the string value, and another is the length specifying the number of characters of that string. Therefore, when you assign like that:

```
strings[0] = "Apple"
```

you're actually assigning a two-word value for this string. If you don't wanna copy the two-word, you have to work with pointers:

```
var strings [5]*string
apple := "Apple"
strings[0] = &apple
```

So, you just copy the pointer of the string, and if you change strings[0] element value, the string itself will be modified. If you're interested in the implementation of strings in go, [here](https://boakye.yiadom.org/go/strings/) is a good explanation.

---